# Browscap.ini issues

Tags: php

I am using the wamp server going through the php tutorials on youtube and i got stuck on the 67th video because i am having problems. I keep getting this error message **"( ! ) Warning: get_browser(): browscap.ini directive not set"**

What i have done so far.

1. Downloaded the browscap.ini file (for PHP use only)
2. placed it in "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/browscap.ini"
3. In the PHP.ini file point to the browscap.ini file using the absolute path

[browscap]

; http://php.net/browscap

browscap = "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/browscap.ini"

Then I Restarted my WAMPSERVER but I'm still having problems

**Can someone please help me with this?**

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: what error still reflecting ?

Comment: What if you try `browscap = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\browscap.ini"` ?

Comment: @ SWAPNESH - The error that I'm getting is: ( ! ) Warning: get_browser(): browscap ini directive not set in C:\wamp\www\$_SERVER\better\tutorial_detect_browser.php on line 3
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0007 138960 {main}( ) ..\tutorial_detect_browser.php:0
2 0.0007 139344 get_browser ( ) ..\tutorial_detect_browser.php:3

Comment: @ HEK2MGL - I tried the slashes however they didn't make a difference. Thanks for your help.